# How to determine the source of a water leak?

Tags: bathroom, water, shower

I live  in an condominium unit and I just newly renovated my bathroom, specifically removing bathtub replacing it with shower.

I hired a non-professional and after 2 days there is some water coming out between the wall and floor tiles beside the shower pan. I closed the main water but still there is some leak.

I don't know where the water is coming from and the worker I hired is out of the country and would be back in a few weeks.

How do I determine where the water is leaking from?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell where a leak is just from a picture. However, historically water on the floor next to a shower pan indicates a leak between the drain and the pan. Depending on the type of drain , you may be able to seal there.

Comment: thank you, but the water is clear and no smell does this mean it is coming from a source ? and is it also possible that there is a leaak in the shower system ?

Comment: Anything is possible.  I'm telling you what is most common in those situations.  You need to realize nobody can tell you exactly what is leaking from a picture of water on a floor.  You need to do some research yourself, or call a plumber.

Comment: Why would you expect the water to be anything _but_ clear and odorless, unless you suspect it's coming from the toilet or kitchen sink? If your non-pro is conveniently "out of the country" for a couple of weeks, it's time to bite the bullet and hire a professional to fix the handyman's mistakes.

Comment: thank you i guess the only way is to get a proffesional plumber

Comment: With few exceptions (wicking can be one) water flows downhill, so it's coming from somewhere above where you found it. More than that is impossible to say.

Comment: Did your non-professional do an air pressure test of any new plumbing before closing up the walls? My guess is "no", but it's always worth asking. Teachable moment: You should always do an air pressure test on new plumbing before the walls are closed back up. Much cheaper and easier to fix leaks then than it is to fix them after everything's buttoned up.

Comment: i have already schedule a plumber but it due end of next week, i  hope you understand that i have limited financial capabilities  but this is a big lesson for me .

Comment: im sorry if i keep on asking questions but i know i can figure it out the only source of water is from the shower and i know they have some problems putting my shower sytem if you see in the picture it is now even leveled and and in case they need to remove the shower tray can use it again of i need to purchase a new one ? thanks for helping

Comment: Is it leaking 24x7, or only when you're running your shower?

Comment: Most people are under some financial pressure, so that's understood. It will be _far_ less expensive to fix this properly _now_ than to wait until there's significant water damage to the structure that _also_ needs to be repaired. Just bite the bullet and get it done now. You may have to eat popcorn (or other cheap food) for a month to pay for it, but it's worth it in the long run - structural repairs could easily be 3, 4, 5x as much as the simple plumbing repair now.